# "object not iterable" in Spotipy

Tags: python, iteration, spotipy

I have this function to extract `audio_features` from an artist seed in `Spotipy`.

```
def show_audio_features(artist):
    tids = []
    results = sp.recommendations(seed_artists = [artist['id']])
    for track in results['tracks']:
        tids.append(track['uri'])
        features = sp.audio_features(tids)
    return json.dumps(features, indent=4)
```

It prints:

```
12:51 - The Strokes
There, There - Radiohead
DARE - Gorillaz
Stand by Me - Oasis
Do You Realize?? - The Flaming Lips
The Scientist - Coldplay
Exit Music (For a Film) - Radiohead
Supremacy - Muse
[
    {
        "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2rA36OZNb3LkvqcNro1ugK", 
        "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/2rA36OZNb3LkvqcNro1ugK", 
        "energy": 0.776, 
        "liveness": 0.0884, 
        "tempo": 113.808, 
        "speechiness": 0.056, 
        "uri": "spotify:track:2rA36OZNb3LkvqcNro1ugK", 
        "acousticness": 0.0395, 
        "instrumentalness": 0.737, 
        "time_signature": 4, 
        "danceability": 0.693, 
        "key": 3, 
        "duration_ms": 319249, 
        "loudness": -9.804, 
        "valence": 0.666, 
        "type": "audio_features", 
        "id": "2rA36OZNb3LkvqcNro1ugK", 
        "mode": 1
    }, etc
```

but apparently, this output is not iterable. If I try

```
  for f in show_audio_features(artist):
     print (f[0])
```

I get:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Is there a way I can prevent the `spotipy` method from outputing songs and artists so I can iterate through `JSON` data?

Comment: I'm pretty certain the issue is with your code. You don't show the line number for the error but I think the error comes from the `print (f[0])` call rather than the `for` loop.

Comment: @theorifice maybe: but if I write `print (f)`, the output is the same..